# Adding multiple images into a canvas

Tags: node.js, canvas, node-canvas

I'm trying to create a "banner" that has information on it, including images.

The banner looks like this:

[image]

An image would be placed on the circle and then text would be in the other areas.

My attempt fails, as an empty image is created.

```
const { createCanvas, loadImage } = require('canvas');
```

```
    const canvas = createCanvas(901, 231)
    const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    const ctxAvatar = canvas.getContext('2d');
    const ctxSkin = canvas.getContext('2d');
    loadImage('assets/images/avatar.png').then(avatar => {
        ctxAvatar.drawImage(avatar, 50, 0, 70, 70);
        loadImage('assets/images/banner.png').then(banner => {
            ctx.drawImage(avatar, 50, 0, 70, 70);
            ctx.drawImage(banner, 50, 0, 70, 70);
        });
    });
    const output = canvas.toBuffer();
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This is kind of hard to test, does your node code generate a html page with a canvas element in it? Do you get 404 errors for the images in the console? I would start by separating the two loadImage calls so you can test them separately. Also, ctxAvatar and ctxSkin are the same. Why do you use "toBuffer" ?

Comment: No, there's no web server attached to this. I also use toBuffer for uploading the image to the discord client (discord.js)

Comment: For now the problem is that your question is not complete. Your loading and drawing of images seems OK, so in your process something else is going wrong. You'll have to provide a minimum working code example so others can replicate your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
const canvas = createCanvas(901, 231)
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
const ctxAvatar = canvas.getContext('2d');
const ctxSkin = canvas.getContext('2d');
loadImage('assets/images/avatar.png').then(avatar => {
    ctxAvatar.drawImage(avatar, 50, 0, 70, 70);
    loadImage('assets/images/banner.png').then(banner => {
        ctx.drawImage(banner, 50, 0, 70, 70);
        const output = canvas.toBuffer();
    });
});
```

The `const output = canvas.toBuffer();` should be inside